# Fetch Multiple rows data from Server using PHP Code

Tags: php

Getting record for first row, but want to get all record(s) available in table for a Particular MemberID

**order_fetch.php**

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("android");

$strMemberID = $_POST["sMemberID"];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE MemberID = '".$strMemberID."' ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if($obResult)
{
$arr["OrderID"] = $obResult["OrderID"];
$arr["MemberID"] = $obResult["MemberID"];
$arr["TotalAmount"] = $obResult["TotalAmount"];
$arr["ItemDetails"] = $obResult["ItemDetails"];
}      
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: hi Chulbul, i think problem is in your PHP code instead of android so u will need to first debug PHP code for current case

Comment: you need to `mysql_fetch_array` for all the rows returned. You are doing it for first  row only. And `loadData()` is not written in way that lets' you iterate over returned json array of objects.

Comment: again such a question: obviously the problem is that you are not doing a loop. Not in PHP (for fetching the results) and not in android (de-parsing the json)...

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a great example of a question that will help the community here. Looks to me you'll have to debug your code to see what's going on.

Do so and while at it give us the content (and type) of the resultServer object and the Data object. Is that Data object even holding a collection?

You can't expect us to implement this or fix this without at least knowing the implementation of these objects? Not to mention the actual json you get from your server implementation.